# Dictionary within a Dictionary is iterating over all values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm reading in an XML file and trying to pull data from it. I need all the instances of 'Description' which has a specific ID associated with the type of Description and then I need the value or text of the Description.

des_id = grabs all the description ids for a item

des_value = grabs all the values for those IDs

des_ids dictionary = associating the des_id with the des_value in a dictionary

descriptions dictionary = associating the item number with the des_ids dictionary

when I go to export to .csv if looks to be the last item number in the xml file description data is iterating over all parts in the list. I need the individual description codes with values for each item number in the file.

Showing a snip of the code where I know it's messing up how I intended.

```
for part in soup.find_all('Item'):


for x in part.find_all('PartNumber'):

    partNum = x.get_text()

    for description in part.find_all('Description'):
        des_id = description.get('DescriptionCode')  # key
        des_value = description.get_text()  # value

        des_ids[des_id] = des_value

        descriptions[partNum] = [des_ids]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

SAMPLE XML:

```
<Items>
    <Item MaintenanceType="A">
      <PartNumber>2000207</PartNumber>
      <Descriptions>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="ASC">Here's a sample ASC description for 2000207</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="ASM">2000207 sample ASM description</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="DEF">2000207 Product</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="DES">This is some text for 2000207</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="EXT">Modified text kit for 2000207</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="INV">Invoice desc for 2000207</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="KEY">THE KEY for 2000207</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="SHO">Pretty Short description for 2000207</Description>
      </Descriptions>
    </Item>
    <Item MaintenanceType="A">
      <HazardousMaterialCode>N</HazardousMaterialCode>
      <PartNumber>2000408</PartNumber>
      <Descriptions>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="ASC">Here's a sample ASC description for 2000208</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="ASM">2000208 sample ASM description</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="DEF">2000208 Product</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="DES">This is some text for 2000208</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="EXT">Modified text kit for 2000208</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="INV">Invoice desc for 2000208</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="KEY">THE KEY for 2000208</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="A" LanguageCode="EN" DescriptionCode="SHO">Pretty Short description for 2000208</Description
      </Description>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

Ouput is 3 column csv with PartNum | des_id | des_value

Comment: "this is not compiling correctly" what do you mean?

Comment: means I have 2000+ parts and with all the same des_id : des_value as the very last part in the list

Comment: Without a sample `XML` nobody can't tell **why**: [Edit] your Question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: I don't think that will help you all that much....but sure, hold on. The des_id pulls what it is supposed to, the des_value pulls what it is supposed to, and the partNum pulls what it is supposed to. So the problem looks to be how I am trying to loop through to compile the dictionary within a dictionary.

Comment: you provided the input, good, now what is the expected output for this input?

Comment: how about create the dictionary, sorry I guess I just don't have the right terminology.

Comment: Ouput is 3 column csv with PartNum | des_id | des_value

Comment: Change the indentation of `descriptions[partNum] = ...`, back to the same level as `for description ...`

Comment: I tried your code and it does exactly what expected. Maybe it's indentation as @stovfl mentioned, maybe you got an older/bugged version of BeautifulSoup?! 
 See [this code here](https://gist.github.com/p-jahn/f2e0d388bd93bad7ea56ea67d2757dc0)

Comment: You're right...I ran the sample file through mine and it works. SO it's something to do with the larger xml file.

Comment: Whole day wasted debugging due to the issue being in the XML file. FML. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: I need the individual description codes with values for each item number in the file.

```
for part in soup.find_all('Item'):
    for x in part.find_all('PartNumber'):
        partNum = x.get_text()
        print("partNum{}".format(partNum))

        for description in part.find_all('Description'):
            des_id = description.get('DescriptionCode')  # key
            des_value = description.get_text()  # value

            csv_data = {'PartNumber': partNum, 'DescriptionCode': des_id, 'Description': des_value}
            print("\t{}".format(csv_data))
```

> **Output**:

```
partNum2000207
    {'DescriptionCode': 'ASC', 'PartNumber': '2000207', 'Description': "Here's a sample ASC description for 2000207"}
    {'DescriptionCode': 'ASM', 'PartNumber': '2000207', 'Description': '2000207 sample ASM description'}
    {'DescriptionCode': 'DEF', 'PartNumber': '2000207', 'Description': '2000207 Product'}
... (omitted for brevity)    
partNum2000408
    {'DescriptionCode': 'ASC', 'PartNumber': '2000408', 'Description': "Here's a sample ASC description for 2000208"}
    {'DescriptionCode': 'ASM', 'PartNumber': '2000408', 'Description': '2000208 sample ASM description'}
    {'DescriptionCode': 'DEF', 'PartNumber': '2000408', 'Description': '2000208 Product'}
 ... (omitted for brevity)
```